# Loop Successful, but ends with "Subscript Out of Range"

Tags: vba, excel, loops, for-loop

I am encountering a peculiarity in my VBA code. The code populates array myArray with data from a table, than pastes the array multiple times, editing data in two columns with each iteration and paste.

The code below executes successfully, but always ends with "Run-time error '9': Subscript out of range".

```
Option Explicit

Public myArray As Variant
Public i As Integer
Public r As Integer
Public slist() As Variant
Public qlist() As Variant
Public comcols() As Variant

---------------------------------------------------------------------------    
Sub Scopier()

myArray = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Semesters").ListObjects("tblSemester").DataBodyRange.Value

slist = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Lists").ListObjects("tblslist").DataBodyRange.Value

For r = 1 To 10
    Call loopthroughs
    Call spit
Next r

End Sub
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
Sub loopthroughs()

For i = 1 To UBound(myArray, 1)
    myArray(i, 5) = slist(r, 2)
    myArray(i, 6) = slist(r, 1)
    myArray(i, 7) = "Upcoming"
    myArray(i, 13) = "Pending"
    myArray(i, 19) = "Scheduling"
    myArray(i, 22) = "Course Schedule"
Next

End Sub
---------------------------------------------------------------------------    
Sub spit()

If IsEmpty(ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A2")) Then
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A2", "V2").Resize(UBound(myArray)).Value = myArray
Else
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0).Activate
    Range(ActiveCell, ActiveCell.Offset(0, 22)).Resize(UBound(myArray)).Value = myArray
End If

End Sub
```

When debugging, the first line within the for loop is where the error occurs, but only after each iteration has been successful.

```
Sub loopthroughs()

For i = 1 To UBound(myArray, 1)
    myArray(i, 5) = slist(r, 2) <------ This line is the debug error
    myArray(i, 6) = slist(r, 1)
    myArray(i, 7) = "Upcoming"
    myArray(i, 13) = "Pending"
    myArray(i, 19) = "Scheduling"
    myArray(i, 22) = "Course Schedule"
Next

End Sub
```

Strangely enough, a slightly modified version of the same code (shown below) executes successfully without this run time error.

```
Sub Qcopier()

myArray = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Quarters").ListObjects("tblquarter").DataBodyRange.Value

qlist = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Lists").ListObjects("tblqlist").DataBodyRange.Value

For r = 1 To 12
    Call loopthroughq
    Call spit
Next r

End Sub
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
Sub loopthroughq()

For i = 1 To UBound(myArray, 1)
    myArray(i, 5) = qlist(r, 2)
    myArray(i, 6) = qlist(r, 1)
    myArray(i, 7) = "Upcoming"
    myArray(i, 13) = "Pending"
    myArray(i, 19) = "Scheduling"
    myArray(i, 22) = "Course Schedule"
Next

End Sub
```

I cannot figure out why the first code block is having this run time error. I imagine the loopthroughs() function is trying to iterate one (or more) times over myArray than it has rows, but I cannot figure out how to amend this.

I have tried slight modifications to the sub loopthroughs(), including changing the Ubound value to Ubound(myArray) and (Ubound(myArray, 1) - 1) but nothing seems to work.

I am up against the limit of my VBA knowledge and could use some help.

Comment: Trying using `Debug.Print myArray(i + 1, 5)` or `MsgBox myArray(i + 1, 5)` to see what the value is. It sounds like you're trying to access something that doesn't exist

Comment: seems you are right and know the problem is the two sizes you are working with are not the same.  you answered your own question with 10 vs 12 . . . why not set the loop to the length of the array.  Careful with a for loop that starts indexing at 1 with arrays that index at 0.  I deal with this is javascript for loops often.

Comment: @wookies-will-code: if the array is filled from a range i think it starts at 1 not 0.

Comment: let me see. writing some code now.

Comment: you are correct array index starts at 1 filling from range, I ran some code and got a lot of subscript errors along the way.  Fun with arrays. Unless you have a 22 dimension array I am not sure we should be using (i, 22).  As two dimensional arrays are (i,2) and one dimensional (i,1).

Comment: thinking you have to also index the dimension in this for loop:For i = 1 To UBound(myArray, 1) as :For i = 1 To UBound(myArray, j) and pass in j being r? Call loopthroughq (r) and Sub loopthroughq(j as Inetger)

Comment: the simplest way for the OP to check the dimensions and bounds is to put a break point after the array is filled and examine the locals window. Could also look at databodyrange row and column counts.

Comment: ^^should give the UBounds of each dimension with  databodyrange row and column counts

Comment: Hi all. I ran a Debug.Print i in the loopthroughs() function. What it showed in the Immediate window was that it ran through i = 1 to i = 111 (the number of rows in the original table), then ran 1 again, which seems to cause the run-time error. - Correction: It runs 25-111, then 1-111 again, then 1.

Comment: doesn't sound right: you are calling each function 10 times in the top code and 12 times in the bottom code.  Are you speaking of the loopthrough loops and not r?  Sounds like you want to kill the last one at any rate.  How are you defining r?

Answer (score 0):

Take some of this error checking and see what is happening with each iteration.
I wrote this for a single dimension.  I am looking for boundaries, the array index, and the array values in the code below.  If I knew what your data looked like (or a dummy set) it would be helpful in working this script.

```
Option Explicit
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim myArray As Variant
Dim toutput As String
Dim indexoutput As String
Dim i As Integer
Dim WKS As Worksheet
Dim rng As Range
Set WKS = ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet
Set rng = WKS.Range("G1:G10")

myArray = rng

'LBound here is 1 and UBound is 10
For i = LBound(myArray, 1) To UBound(myArray, 1)
indexoutput = indexoutput & i & " // "
toutput = toutput & myArray(i, 1) & ", "
Next i

MsgBox LBound(myArray, 1) & vbCrLf & UBound(myArray, 1) & vbCrLf & indexoutput & vbCrLf & toutput

End Sub
```

https://excelmacromastery.com/excel-vba-array/

It shows accessing 2D arrays as:

```
For i = LBound(arr,1) To UBound(arr,1)
  For j = LBound(arr,2) To UBound(arr,2)
  Next j
Next i
```

And to look at all items as:

```
Dim item As Variant
   For Each item In arr
Next item
```

Pretty sure we can get to the bottom of the size problem pretty quickly.

But I can't see your ranges in these table and list definitions, you need to provide more info.

```
  myArray = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Semesters").ListObjects("tblSemester").DataBodyRange.Value

    slist = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Lists").ListObjects("tblslist").DataBodyRange.Value
```

Answer (score 0):

When I changed the for loop in scopier() from

```
For r = 1 To 10
    Call loopthroughs
    Call spit
Next r
```

to

```
For r = 1 To Ubound(slist)
    Call loopthroughs
    Call spit
Next r
```

everything worked fine. Thanks for all the help in running diagnostics!